# Communicate between sessions

Tags: r

What is the effective way of communicate between different R sessions/instances?

lets say to share global variables or send signals to each other.

Comment: i mean for realtime communication between 2 R consoles. I cant find the way to work with workspace here.

Comment: Maybe through sockets? http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/make.socket.html

Comment: Why do you want to? What's the scope of what you want to do? The bigmemory allows for bigmatrices accessible between different instances. I'm sure other memory mapped packages might have something similar. Rserve should help with sending stuff between sessions but doesn't support callbacks, but you could roll your own for that by making sure they are both running rserve or something like that.

Comment: socket is a gd idea. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [Rserve](http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/web/packages/Rserve/index.html), or there is a video of using [svSocket](http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/web/packages/svSocket/index.html) for passing data between client and server on the [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) homepage.

Comment: I am trying with svSocket. Console 1: startSocketServer(port=8888) console 2: con = socketConnection(port=8888) L=1:10 evalServer(con, L). Keep getting back the error: Error in evalServer(con, L) : Unable to find <<<startflag>>> In addition: Warning message: In 0:(endloc - 1) : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used

Comment: @SilverSpoon. Hm, not sure. Try reporting to the maintainer of svSocket (certainly before posting to r-help, as per posting guide),  or,  post a new question here on Stack Overflow. Have you already Google'd for the error message?

Comment: Ive found a similar unanswered post: https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1657&group_id=194&atid=797

Comment: Do you use the existing evalServer in svSocket and have your own? I am trying to look into that file.

Comment: @SilverSpoon Great, good progress. Then please chase the maintainer :-)

Comment: The new patch will be released soon